# Serialization issues with ServiceStack followed by SEGV on mono 2.10.8.1

Tags: mono, servicestack, segmentation-fault

I'm running Service Stack under Linux / mono 2.10.8.1 and I seem to be encountering some serialization issues where the deserializer is looking for properties on the wrong class.  Then null reference exception in EndpointHandlerBase, and finally my process dies with a SEGV.  Here are some logs to illustrate:

ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer [(null)] - Property 'blah' does not exist on type 'some.class'
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase [(null)] - Error occurred while Processing Request: Object reference not set to an instance of an object 
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Utils.FilterAttributeCache.GetRequestFilterAttributes(System.Type requestDtoType)
...

within the same second, I get a SEGV that kills the process:
main process (6469) killed by SEGV signal

Any idea what is causing this?  I suspect that the serialization mappings are being munged, possibly due to some intense garbage collection going on under heavy load.  Is anyone else experiencing the same when running under mono?

Comment: No-one will be able to help if you don't supply enough info to be able to repro it. i.e. What's the impl that caused this? how was it called? Where's the full stacktrace, etc.

Comment: It's not very reproducible - the code works fine for a while and then suddenly JSON serialization errors start. It occurs quite sporadically. This is just a basic Get operation on a service with a request filter, so there isn't really much to it.  Guess nobody hits this issue.

Comment: After a bunch of research, I think I'm hitting this mono bug with a race condition setting up vtables which is reported fixed, but looking at the 2.10.8.1 sources, it doesn't appear to be: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3676

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to upgrade to a newer Mono.  The problem does not occur in Mono 3.x.